# How to resize a WPF Window in increments?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to make a `Window` such that when it's resized in height by the user, it increments and decrements by 10? Sort of like snapping resize.

Comment: What would be the use-case for a feature like that?

Comment: I have a TreeView inside a WPF Window where it shows all the layers in an image. So when the user resizes it, I want it so that the scaling reveals or hide a complete TreeView row, instead of having a TreeView item partially shown/hidden.

Comment: Don't forget that the user may be running with different appearance settings: Font Face, Font Size, screen DPI, etc. may all be different. You'll need to do some math to find the actual snap value, and a lot of testing to make sure it's correct with all settings, on all versions of windows.

Comment: That's a good point, I only need to support Win7 64 but users might change dpi I think. But anything else shouldn't matter though right? Like font face, font size, what are those for? OS-wide font settings? Because my controls use font and hard coded sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how this can be done:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace DeleteMeWPF {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

            IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(this.WindowProc));
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct RECT {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        private const int WM_SIZING = 0x0214;

        private const int WMSZ_BOTTOM = 6;
        private const int WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT = 7;
        private const int WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT = 8;
        private const int WMSZ_LEFT = 1;
        private const int WMSZ_RIGHT = 2;
        private const int WMSZ_TOP = 3;
        private const int WMSZ_TOPLEFT = 4;
        private const int WMSZ_TOPRIGHT = 5;

        private const int SnappingIncrement = 100;
        private const int SnappingThresholdWidth = 300;
        private const int SnappingThresholdHeight = 400;

        private IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
            switch (msg) {
                case WM_SIZING:
                    RECT bounds = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(RECT));

                    int width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
                    int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

                    switch (wParam.ToInt32()) {
                        case WMSZ_BOTTOM:
                            if (height > SnappingThresholdHeight)
                                bounds.bottom = bounds.top + ((int)((double)height / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            break;
                        case WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT:
                            if (height > SnappingThresholdHeight)
                                bounds.bottom = bounds.top + ((int)((double)height / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            if (width > SnappingThresholdWidth)
                                bounds.left = bounds.right - ((int)((double)width / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            break;
                        case WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT:
                            if (height > SnappingThresholdHeight)
                                bounds.bottom = bounds.top + ((int)((double)height / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            if (width > SnappingThresholdWidth)
                                bounds.right = bounds.left + ((int)((double)width / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            break;
                        case WMSZ_LEFT:
                            if (width > SnappingThresholdWidth)
                                bounds.left = bounds.right - ((int)((double)width / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            break;
                        case WMSZ_RIGHT:
                            if (width > SnappingThresholdWidth)
                                bounds.right = bounds.left + ((int)((double)width / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            break;
                        case WMSZ_TOP:
                            if (height > SnappingThresholdHeight)
                                bounds.top = bounds.bottom - ((int)((double)height / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            break;
                        case WMSZ_TOPLEFT:
                            if (width > SnappingThresholdWidth)
                                bounds.left = bounds.right - ((int)((double)width / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            if (height > SnappingThresholdHeight)
                                bounds.top = bounds.bottom - ((int)((double)height / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            break;
                        case WMSZ_TOPRIGHT:
                            if (width > SnappingThresholdWidth)
                                bounds.right = bounds.left + ((int)((double)width / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            if (height > SnappingThresholdHeight)
                                bounds.top = bounds.bottom - ((int)((double)height / (double)SnappingIncrement) * SnappingIncrement);
                            break;

                    }
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(bounds, lParam, false);
                    break;
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

This uses increments of 100 to really illustrate the "snapping" effect. In addition, you can adjust the snapping thresholds, which ensure the snapping only takes effect when the size is above a given width/height.

Comment: Thanks, so should I refer to unmanaged Win32 API to do this? If this is how it needs to be done, then I will use it.

Comment: +1 I was just writing something similar but you beat me to it. One thing is that you should probably also account for is the [wParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632647(v=VS.85).aspx). As it probably matters where the sizing is coming from (Bottom, BottomLeft, Top, TopLeft, etc). Still I agree with Henk Holterman that this is probably not ideal since it violates the Principle of Least Astonishment

Comment: I just tried it and it works great but one thing I need to know is if I can modify this to make it still say increments of 10 but after a certain size. For instance the base size is 366 and from there it could be +/- 10, where as this one seems to jump to a value divisible by 100 immediately, instead of adding, subtracting 100 from the initial size, right?

Comment: @Joan Venge you'll just need to test `bounds.Right - bounds.left` and `bound.top - bounds.bottom` before you modify it and call `StructureToPtr`

Comment: Thanks Conrad, actually you were also right with the wParam comment. When I resized from the top, it resized from the bottom awkwardly. Is it possible you show me how to do that? Edit the code if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: @Joan Venge - Updated to include Conrad's excellent comment and your additional requirement of only applying it after a given size. You may be able to use the Window.DesiredSize as the snapping threshold. But if not, then you'd need to calculate a value based on the child's desired size.

Answer (score 3):

The old Win32 Listbox had a setting to prevent that. Note that that was solving the problem from the other end.

But take a look at a few established TreeViews first. Like Visual Studio, Tools Options.

I don't think you should be modifying the behaviour of std UI controls this way. Users will only be frustrated if your TV acts 'differently'. They won't call it 'better'.

Comment: Really the old ListBox has a setting to prevent that. Why would they do that? :O Also of course before releasing it like this, I wanted to try it out myself first and get some idea of it.

Comment: Visual Studio's Tools/Options isn't a resizeable window. What behavior are you pointing out here?

Comment: @David: I can see a few pixels of the next row at the bottom.

Comment: @Henk, I just checked the options window, but on Win7, I can't see a few pixels of the last item, so it looks cropped. IMO this looks ugly. It would look better if I could see the items fully at every position, scroll IMO. Also another thing is which might be minor but my target audience is artists and sometimes this kind of minutia is discussed to death :O

Comment: @Joan The INTEGRAL_HEIGHT feature was little used and not implemented on newer Controls.

Comment: That's the name of the feature you were talking about that prevents this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

It may not be very nice to have the window become a size the user didn't want... what would happen if they maximize the window, and it's not a multiple of 10? Would you be able to keep the other window borders in the same place if they dragged the top edge of the window?

I'd instead focus on the TreeView: Make a container that implements MeasureOverride, and have the implementation call the base.MeasureOverride, and when it gets that result, rounds the values down (always down) to a multiple of 10. The rest of your window contents will get a varying amount of space, depending on the size of the window, but just make sure you've got something in your layout that will stretch to take up the extra 0-9 pixels.

Comment: You made some good points. Although since this window is like a toolwindow inside the main app, they are only able to resize it in height and for that, there is no maximize or set it to full screen, just dragging it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, normally you would want to handle the Resize/Resizing event and then round up or down the size to a multiple of ten or something of the sort.

However in WPF you apparently have to resort to a hack using behaviors.

See [this article](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/09/a-wpf-behavior-for-window-resize-events-in-net-35) as it describes what you have to do to access the resizing event.

Comment: I tried to add the Resize events but they don't show up for a Window in the Xaml editor. You mean using these events for the Window, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly add a SizeChangedEventHandler to the SizeChanged event. Then inside your delegate method, change the size manually.

Though I think it would be hard to know how much it has changed unless you record it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was about to say : "In a esay way, and by not writing dirty-twisty code-behind ? Not to my knowledge".

... I'll stick to that xD